# Not able to sign in using github in firebase

Tags: angular, firebase-authentication

I am using firebase authentication to allow users to login using their social accounts. Authentications works successfully for google and facebook and normal sign-in. But there is some problem with Twitter and Github sign-in process:

1. In case of Github, after I provide correct credentials in the pop-up window for Github, instead of signing-in, it throws error "auth/popup-closed-by-user". The pop-up closes automatically (expected behavior) but then it directly throws the error, so I'm not even able to debug what went wrong. I have tried it a lot of times (chrome, safari) but it throws the same error. Here is my code:

`loginGit(): Promise<any> {
        return firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GithubAuthProvider())
        .then((result) => {
            // go to home...
        }).catch ( (error) => {
            if (error.code === 'auth/account-exists-with-different-credential') {
                const pendingCred = error.credential;
                // The provider account's email address.
                const email = error.email;
                // Get registered providers for this email.
                firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail(email).then( (providers) => {
                    if (providers[0] === 'password') {
                        const password = this.promptUserForPassword(providers[0]);
                        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then( (user)  => {
                            return user.linkWithCredential(pendingCred);
                        }).then( ( user) => {
                        });
                        return;
                    }
                    const provider = this.getProviderId(providers[0]);
                    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then( (result) => {
                        result.user.linkWithCredential(pendingCred).then( (user) => {
                            this.afterSignIn();
                        });
                    });
                });
            } else {
                alert('Some problem, please try later..');
            }
        });
    }`

2. In case of Twitter, since we don't get the email address of the user (in firebase.auth().currentUser object) signed-in using Twitter, if same/other user sign-up using same email address with other provider like google or simply login (with email and password), how would I check whether there's already an existing account with same/new user's email address. 
   In case of facebook, google and password, I check it using following code

   `if (error.code === 'auth/wrong-password') {
                   let providers = [];
                   firebase.auth().fetchProvidersForEmail(form.email)
                   .then((p) => {
                       providers = p;
                   // some other code...
                   }).catch((error) => {
                     // handle error
                   });
    } else { // .....}`

   If anyone has also faced such issues, please let me know how to to resolve them.

Comment: There may be an issue with your GitHub OAuth configuration. Also inspect the browser console for any errors that could shed some light on this. For Twitter you can request access to email. You would need to file a request for that with Twitter. Otherwise, Firebase will not enforce account linking if no email is returned.

Comment: @bojeil Thanks for your suggestions. I created a new app in Github and used it for authentication. In case of Twitter, I will file a request for email in case I don’t find any other way resolve this issue.